# How can I assess if a parametric model can reproduce the same curve with different parameters?

Tags: model, curve-fitting, nonparametric

I have a parametric model that I think it is "degenerate" in the sense that I can obtain the same model with different parameters.

For example, if I have a convolution of two 1D Gaussians (say, G1 and G2), I'll obtain another Gaussian G3 with a standard deviation of $\sigma_3 = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}$, where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are the deviations of the convolved Gaussians. The same G3 curve can be obtained with different $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ by "balancing" them, so if I want to fit G3 to data through its parameters $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, I can choose multiple values for them and still get a good fit.

So my questions are:

1. Is "degenerate" the correct term for calling this model?
2. How can I assess if a model is degenerate?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, degenerate is an appropriate term.